# Should variables and strings be treated differently in constructing a language?

Tags: parsing, haskell, read-eval-print-loop

I'm currently working on a language and have come to an issue regarding variable declarations in that to check what value a variable is in the REPL, I must use quotation marks.

```
> x := 1
> "x"
1
```

The desired behaviour however would be the following:

```
> x := 1
> x
1
```

I have defined my ADT in the following way:

```
data S = Integer Integer | String String | Assign String S | Expr Add [S]
```

I can parse everything correctly.

```
parseString :: Parser HVal
parseString = char '"' *> many1 (noneOf "\"") <* char '"' >>= (return . String)

parseAssign :: Parser HVal
parseAssign = do
         var <- many1 letter
         spaces
         string ":="
         spaces
         val <- try (parsersHVal)
         spaces
         return $ Assign var val
```

I think however that the problem is done to the evaluation functions.

```
evalHVal :: Env -> HVal -> IOThrowsError HVal
evalHVal env val@(Integer _)  = return $ val
evalHVal env val@(String  _)  = return $ val
evalHVal env (String  val)    = getVar env val >>= \var -> evalHVal env var
```

If I keep the first line that evaluates a string, the following occurs in the REPL and I receive a warning that the second line is redundant:

```
> x := 1
> "x"
'x'
```

If I keep the second line however I get the behaviour as described from the beginning.

In both cases, quotations around the variable have to be placed in order to evaluate it. I recongise though that I use `many1 letter` rather than `parseString` in the function `parseAssign`. I have tried changing this to `parseString` but I obtain the same behaviour.

What confuses me the most however is that since everything is read in as a string, then why doesn't `many1 letter` require quotations in `parseAssign` like how `parseString` requires? I tried changing `parseString` to the following (`many1 letter >>= (return . String)`) but it neither assigns nor allows for the use of strings like before.

Comment: While `> x` should evaluate the AST `Variable "x"` or something like that, `> "x"` should evaluate the AST `StringLiteral "x"`. I don't see why they should be treated the same at all.

Comment: @user My line of thought was that you could possibly cut down on the amount of code by considering that since variables are also strings, then all you need is a helper function to check if a current string is a variable or not, otherwise consider it a string literal

Comment: You should distinguish between identifiers and strings. `x` is an identifier that could have an integer value. `"x"` should always be a string value, not a variable.

Comment: But strings are values, and variables are not at all the same thing as values. I'd say it's a lot more important for your code to make sense than it is to make it shorter.

Comment: Variables are strings in your *source code*, not in your *data model*. Everything in your source code is a string; the important thing is what your parser turns those strings into.

Comment: Do you really want `"y"` to be parsed differently depending on whether it is preceded by `y := 1` or not? (The difference between defined and undefined `y` is a matter for your evaluation function, not your parser.)

Comment: @chepner That makes a lot more sense than what I was thinking, thank you!

Comment: If, say, Python's `eval` worked like yours, it would print `1` for `x=1;print(eval("'x'"))` instead of `'x'`. Do you see how that doesn't make sense? The way you're doing it, the evaluation is "drilling" into the string one layer too deep.

Comment: @user I do indeed, I'm going to make the amendments now!

Comment: Great, and good luck with your language! You may want to edit or delete your question now.

Comment: I'll edit it, incase anyone else runs into the same incorrect way of thinking about this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should variables and strings be treated differently in constructing a language?

Yes

```
data S = ...
```

Should be:

```
data S = ... | Var String
```

> What confuses me the most however is that since everything is read in as a string, then why doesn't many1 letter require quotations in parseAssign like how parseString requires?

That should be obvious.  See the definition:

```
parseString = char '"' *>  ...
```

The very first part of parseString clearly looks to parse `char '"'`.

The definition of parseAssign does not look for `"`.

> I tried changing parseString to the following (many1 letter >>= (return . String)) but it neither assigns nor allows for the use of strings like before.

Well `"` is not a `letter` so it shouldn't/wouldn't allow for a quotation mark.  More, it wouldn't "assign", whatever that verb means, because it lacks the `Assign` constructor along with all the other critical parts of `parseAssign`.

Answer (score 2):

Variables and strings should be considered differently. Although they're both strings in the source language, they cannot be treated identically as they are distinct within the data model of the language.